# findFragmentById() returns null when moving fragment into framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my .xml for the current view:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".nav">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

   <ImageButton
       android:text="Center"
       android:onClick="centerMap"
       android:id="@+id/center_button"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:src="@drawable/center_button_iconn"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
       android:layout_height="55dp"
       android:layout_gravity="start|bottom" />

   <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:name="nuathackmit.yo.NavigationDrawerFragment"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Originally, my fragments (and ImageButton) existed outside of the framelayout. However, since I wanted the organize which object appeared above which, I moved them into the framelayout.

However:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Where this code originally worked, it now returns an NPE.

How do I get the fragment by ID when moved into a FrameLayout?

Comment: The drawer Fragment shouldn't be in the container FrameLayout.

Comment: Why do you have xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in your layout twice? Try removing it and see if it makes a difference.